# Groovy List all properties for class

Tags: groovy, properties

I'm trying to list the properties (i.e. all properties that have a getter method) using Groovy. I can do this using `myObj.properties.each { k,v -> println v}` and that works fine. But, that also prints for the entire superclass hierarchy as well. If I just want to list the properties for the current class (and not the super class), is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way that I hacked out but maybe you can build on it.

```
class Abc {

    def a
    def b

}

class Xyz extends Abc {
    def c
    def d
}

def xyz = new Xyz(c:1,d:2)

xyz.metaClass.methods.findAll{it.declaringClass.name == xyz.class.name}.each { 
    if(it.name.startsWith("get"))  {
        println  xyz.metaClass.invokeMethod(xyz.class,xyz,it.name,null,false,true)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. That's what I was thinking, but was hoping there was a "groovier" way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Try with the following:

```
myObj.declaredFields.collect{it.name}
```

Comment: This will get things that are not properties though. It will get all fields - I was looking for things with getters only.

Comment: `declaredFields` works on the class, so this should read `myObj.getClass().declaredFields.collect{it.name}`